# PHP absolute path with timThumb doesn't work

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm writing a wordpress plugin, and using this script to resize images: [Timthumb](http://www.darrenhoyt.com/2008/04/02/timthumb-php-script-released/)

This script uses absolute paths, but I can't get it to work for me; I've triple-checked all my paths but still nothing.

Here is my code:

```
$plugin_dir_name = "my-plugin";

$pathTimThumb = WP_PLUGIN_URL . '/' . $plugin_dir_name . '/timthumb.php';
$pathToUpload = WP_CONTENT_URL.'/uploads/'.$plugin_dir_name;
$hImg = 150;
$wImg = 150;

....

$myImage = '<img class="thumb" src="'.$pathImageThumb.'?src='.$pathToUpload.'/'.$allImages[$i].'&h='.$hImg.'&w='.$wImg.'&zc=1" alt="">';
```

In firebug I get this URL:

```
<img alt="" src="http://localhost/mu/wp-content/plugins/my-plugin/timthumb.php?src=http://localhost/mu/wp-content/uploads/my-plugin/car___1/26zhoar5.jpg&amp;h=150&amp;w=150&amp;zc=1" class="thumb">
```

Where is the mistake?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use this one.

```
 $my_plugin_url = plugins_url('my-plugin-name/');
    $my_timthumb_url = $my_plugin_url.'timthumb.php?';
    $my_image_url = 'http://localhost/images/image.jpg';
echo '<img alt="" src="'.$my_timthumb_url.'src='.$my_image_url.'&amp;h=150&amp;w=150&amp;zc=1"/>';
```

things to consider to make timthumb work:

- chmod your timthumbs cache folder
- do not use external images
- check you timthumb version

Cheers,Dave

Answer (score 0):

`WP_CONTENT_URL` is a url, not an absolute path. Use `WP_CONTENT_DIR` instead.

Comment: I know that,also try that.Image is loaded in browser when just paste this url in browser http://localhost/mu/wp-content/uploads/my-plugin/car___1/26zhoar5.jpg. Dont know where is mistake,it is annoying :(

Answer (score 0):

TimThumb tries to determine the *local* path of the image by stripping out `http://CURRENT_HOST.tld` from the beginning of the `src` parameter.

Since you're running on `localhost` it might be getting a little confused and falsely calculating it as an external image. I doubt this is the case (I checked the source and it should be OK), but it's an educated guess.

Have you tried reading the HTTP response headers from `http://localhost/mu/wp-content/plugins/my-plugin/timthumb.php?src=http://localhost/mu/wp-content/uploads/my-plugin/car___1/26zhoar5.jpg&amp;h=150&amp;w=150&amp;zc=1`?

If not, use [HttpFox for FireFox](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/6647/) and post back the results.

Comment: When I upload plugin on site it works fine,it just wont work on localhost,I dont know why.Tnx for help.

Comment: Yah, so have you checked the HTTP response headers? As I said, the fact you're running under localhost is probably *why* it's not working.

Comment: After reinstalling XAMPP it is working fine also and in a localhost.Tnx for your time and responses.